# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using spring-social-twitter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, twitter

I try using Twitter API via Spring library `spring-social-twitter`. However I'm when calling `sendDirectMessage(String toScreenName, String text)` function I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode()'
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterErrorHandler.handleError(TwitterErrorHandler.java:56) ~[spring-social-twitter-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:864) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:804) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:503) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.DirectMessageTemplate.sendDirectMessage(DirectMessageTemplate.java:77) ~[spring-social-twitter-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.twittertest.TwitterController.send(TwitterController.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
```

I have the my `TwitterTemplate` configured as following:

```
@Component
public class TwitterTemplateCreator {
    public Twitter getTwitterTemplate() {
        return new TwitterTemplate(
                "<cosumerKey>",
                "<consumerSecret>",
                "<accessToken>",
                "<accessTokenSecret>");
    }
}
```

`TwitterController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(("/api"))
public class TwitterController {
    @Autowired
    private TwitterTemplateCreator twitterTemplateCreator;

    @PostMapping(value = "/send")
    public void send(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("text") String text) {
        twitterTemplateCreator.getTwitterTemplate().directMessageOperations().sendDirectMessage(name, text);
    }
}
```

And finally `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>twitter-test</name>
    <description>twitter-test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My guess is that there is inconsistency with dependencies versions but after trying different Spring Boot versions I still can't figure out what causes this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by defining my own OAuth1 Rest Template using `spring-social`.
First included following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create new temlate which extends `AbstractOAuth1ApiBinding`:

```
public class TwitterTemplate extends AbstractOAuth1ApiBinding {
    public static final String TWITTER_API = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1";
    public TwitterTemplate(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken,
                           String accessTokenSecret) {
        super(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
    }
    public TwitterUserResponse getUser(String name) {
        return getRestTemplate().getForObject(
                TWITTER_API + "/users/show.json?screen_name={name}", TwitterUserResponse.class, name);
    }
}
```

Then just instantiate `TwitterTemplate` and call needed method.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. [Spring Social Twitter](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-social-twitter) is no longer maintained. The last release, 1.1.2.RELEASE, was made in October 2015 and it depends on Spring Framework 4. Spring Boot 1.x is based on Spring Framework 4.x but it has been [out of support since 2019](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support).

I would recommend that you find an alternative to Spring Social Twitter. The alternative would be to use it with Spring Boot 1.x but then you will be using unsupported software for which bug fixes won't be available. Even if you're happy to take that risk, there's also a good chance that Spring Social Twitter isn't compatible with the current version of Twitter's API.

Comment: That's unlucky, is there any alternative that can be used for Twitter API v1.1? Or perhaps some OAuth 1.0 library?